# Can I check values in two columns and all rows to add a conditional value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is what I am trying to do.
I am entering a list of leaves in one sheet with To and From date values. Now given a date  I want to find out whether there is a leave on that date. How can I do that?

For instance, I add following data in excel

```
Jack   | 1-Jan-2014  | 3-Jan-2014
Jill   | 15-Jan-2014 | 15-Jan-2014
```

Now I want to check whether Jill is on leave on 2nd Jan, how can I write a formula to check all the date ranges in two columns?

Now I am now trying to write a custom function to do that. But want to know whether we can do that OOTB.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS`. This:

```
=COUNTIFS($B:$B,"<="&D2,$C:$C,">="&D2)
```

will tell you how many leaves contain the date in `D2`, where leaves start in column `B` and end in column `C`.